# Spark left outer join when left side key is Option[]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, left-join, rdd

I have

```
val rdd1 :  RDD[(Option[String], (String, Option[Context]))]
```

and

```
val rdd2 : RDD[(String,Double)]
```

Now, I would like to `rdd1.leftOuterJoin(rdd2)` but of course I can't because `Option[String]` is different than `String`.

The rationale for the join operation is that in case rdd1's key contains some value, I would like to have an additional info on it. The desired output is of type: `RDD[(Options[String],((String, Option[Context]),Option[Double]))`

What's the bypass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply map `rdd2` to `RDD[(Option[String], Double)]`:

```
rdd1.leftOuterJoin(rdd2.map{case (k, v) => (Option(k), v)})
```

If `Context` can be expressed using Spark SQL types then you can simply convert both RDDs to DataFrames and join. `None` are mapped to `NULLs` so everything should work as expected.